# Rust Lifetimes Behaviour

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to understand lifetimes through the Programming Rust book, and made a custom example here:

```
fn simple_fn(point: [&i32; 3]) -> (&i32, &i32) {
    (point[0], point[2])
}

fn main() {
    let mut point: [&i32; 3] = [&19, &18, &17];

    {
        let x = 3;
        point[1] = &x;
        point[1] = &10;
    }

    let t = simple_fn(point);
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

The compiler returns an error:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
9  |         let x = 3;
   |             - binding `x` declared here
10 |         point[1] = &x;
   |                    ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
11 |         point[1] = &10;
12 |     }
   |     - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
13 |
14 |     let t = simple_fn(point);
   |                       ----- borrow later used here
```

I don't understand, when I have re-assigned `point[1]` to `&10`, right after its assignment to `x`, then why is lifetime of `point[1]` still limited to lifetime of `x`?

Comment: Some of this behavior almost surely derives from the fact that you're using numeric literals, which the compiler treats as `'static`? Or perhaps because they're `Copy`? Or both? If you replace the `&i32` with `&String` you'll see that the equivalent of `points[1] = &10` no longer works either because the `String` gets dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the confusion comes from the fact that the following is valid:

```rust
let mut point = &1;

{
    let x = 3;
    point = &x;
    point = &10;
}

println!("{:?}", point); // Prints `10`
```

The above is valid, because the compiler can infer that `i` is completely replaced. So `i` from that point forward, has the lifetime of `&10` instead of `&x`.

---

Let's use an easier example to understand why your example doesn't work.

Let's consider a `Vec<&i32>` instead. Everything remains the same, but instead of indexing, let's use `.push()` and `.clear()`.

If we instead `.push(&x)` does the example then work? What if we `.clear()` before `.push(10)`, does it work then?

```rust
let mut point = Vec::new();

{
    let x = 3;
    point.push(&x);

    point.clear();

    point.push(&10);
}

println!("{:?}", point);
```

Does the above compile?

No, it results in the exact same error as the one you're encountering. Why? Well, that might be a lot more clear now. Yes, we're calling `.clear()` which results in `&x` being removed. However, the compiler doesn't know that, by simply looking at the function definition of `clear()`. So the lifetime tied to the `Vec<&i32>` remains as the shortest (observed) lifetime by the compiler, which is that of `&x`.

---

Now, when you do:

```
points[1] = &x;
```

That is actually just syntactic sugar for:

```rust
*point.index_mut(1) = &x;
```

So again, looking at [`fn index_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html#tymethod.index_mut) the compiler doesn't know from that, that some `index` would extend the lifetime of the container.

Again, the reason the compiler knows in the first example. Is because `point` is reassigned, so it receives a new lifetime from that point forward. However, calling an `fn(&mut self, usize)` method doesn't tell anything about that.

---

In theory, there could be a special case in the compiler, where when a constant index is used, then it would extend the lifetime of the container in this scenario.

However, such a special case might quickly end up being confusing. Since now if you replace a constant `1` with an `index` variable. Then the lifetime of the container could drastically change out of nowhere.

```rust
// With a special case, this would then pass
point[1] = &x;

// Whereas this would fail
let i = 1;
point[i] = &x;
```

Additionally, it's way more likely that someone is indexing a container using an `index` variable. So the special case would also rarely kick in.

Comment: While insightful, I'm not sure this answer is totally correct. Take a look at this alternative [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39d7260e528b8fbaf410f68d6b8c96a8) , according to your explanation it should work, but it fails with the same error. I suspect the real reason may have to do with lifetime covariance, but I can't explain the details :-(.

Comment: @rodrigo Honestly, I like that example more, than my `Vec` example. I don't think I implied, that your example would work. Because that neither reassigning a variable. In your example, a tuple field is being assigned to. Again, the whole variable needs to be reassigned, otherwise the lifetime associated with the variable isn't _replaced_

Comment: @rodrigo I'm pretty sure it's not related to variance in any way. It looks like the compiler just treats a variable assignment specifically, and doesn't do that for field assignments.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: You are right, assignment looks necessary. I think that it is allowed to assign a value to a variable if it is of a _sub-type_ of the declared type, and there comes the variance, as that is the only kind of sub-typing in Rust. My previous example can be made to work with a full [assignment](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2e53f7ef1b5b1c2190a880d4c0f14af).